# what is the fastest way to update thousands rows in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, performance

- lets assume you have a table with 1M rows and growing ...
- every five minutes of every day you run a python programm which have to update some fields of 50K rows

my question is: what is the fastest way to do the work?

- runs those updates in loop and after last one is executed than fire up a cursor commit?
- or generate file and than run it throught command line?
- create temp table by huge and fast insert and than run a single update to production table?
- do prepared statements?
- split it up to 1K updates per execute, to generate smaller logs files?
- turn off logging while running update?
- or do a cases in mysql [examples](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/articles/sql/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/) (but this works only up to 255 rows)

i dont know ... have anyone do something like this? what is the best practise? i need to run it as fast as possible ...

Comment: How about reading? is db read for %90 time or db only to keep information and wrote for %90 time, and read %10 time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some ways you could speed up your `UPDATES`.

When you `UPDATE`, the table records are just being rewritten with new data. And all this must be done again on `INSERT`. That's why you should always use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE`.

The former one is an `UPDATE` operation in case of a key violation, while the latter one is `DELETE / INSERT`

Here's an example `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;` More on this [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

**UPDATE1:** It's a good idea to do your inserts all in a single query. This should speed up your `UPDATES`. See [**here**](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/articles/sql/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/) on how to do that.

**UPDATE2:** Now that I have had a chance to read your other sub-questions. Here's what I know-

- instead of in a loop, try to execute all `UPDATE` in a single sql & single commit.
- Not sure this is going to make any difference. `SQL` queries are more important.
- Now this is something you could experiment with. Benchmark it. This kind of a thing depends on the size of the `TABLE` & the `INDEXES` you have, plus `INNODB or MYISAM`.
- No idea about this.
- refer first point.
- Yes, this might speed your stuff up slightly. Also see if you have `slow_query_log` turned on. This logs all slow queries to a separate logfile. Turn this off too.
- Again. refer first point.

Comment: all right thanks but how you want to update 50K rows in s single sql?

Answer (score 0):

query execution process:  Server first parsing your query then execute you need to analysis
the query

then server take less time to parse then he execute faster instead of slow in other way